# django-nonrel specify MongoDB BSON element name to model attributes

Tags: python, mongodb, django-nonrel, bson

In C# it is possible to use the MongoDB driver to define a custom BSONElement Name to each attribute in your data models, in order to shorten its stored name, such as

```
[BsonElement("c")]
public Boolean Current { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with a django-nonrel setup and a model defined like

```
class Test(models.Model):
    Current = models.BooleanField()
```

so that the attribute "Current" will be stored as "c" and be referenced in code as "Current"?
Research did not work very well on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the db_column option to BooleanField, or any field -- that should be the actual field name stored in MongoDB.